# Can I fix this recursive function so that the calls aren't deep?

Tags: r, recursion, stack-overflow

I am taking a class on R, and I've been asked to implement Newton's square root method. I've done this before, but in functional languages using tail recursion where the stack doesn't fill because the math is done with each recursive call and not on callbacks.

I have implemented the function. But am getting: 'Error: C stack usage  15924912 is too close to the limit' when I apply the function to very large numbers. I was wondering if my function could be revised to fix this issue.

```
my_sqr <- function(number, sqrt_guess = 1) {
  if (abs((number/sqrt_guess) - sqrt_guess) < .001) sqrt_guess
  else my_sqr(number, improve_guess(number,sqrt_guess))
}

improve_guess <- function(number, guess) {
  return ((guess + (number/guess)) / 2)
}

# test your script on few examples here, example
# Note I will use the results in check1, check2, check3 to grade your sqrt function
# my_test1 <- my_sqr(16)
# my_test2 <- my_sqr(25)
# my_test3 <- my_sqr(400)
# my_test4 <-my_sqr(5000000000000000)
check1 <- my_sqr(2)
check2 <- my_sqr(1e-60)
check3 <- my_sqr(1e+60)
```

The function works on every test except the last call "my_sqr(1e+60)". This is where I get the error.

Comment: With `my_sqr(1e56)` the function calls itself `1447` before breaking. It seems you are hitting a limit.

Comment: Instead of writing a recursive function, use a `while` loop.

Comment: And fix the test for termination:  if the number is really big, it might never be satisfied.

Comment: R does not optimize tail recursion. This operation shouldn't be used since there is no need for reuse of prior results. My guess is that this exercise was given to you to teach you about this limitation of R.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That error prevets you from get into an never-end loop. You can use this function instead but, using 1e+56 or higher may be never ends...

```
#here you can see those limits
Cstack_info()

#here is the code

library(rbenchmark)  

new_my_sqr <- function(number, sqrt_guess = 1) {
    while (abs((number/sqrt_guess) - sqrt_guess) > .001) {
        sqrt_guess <- ((sqrt_guess + (number/sqrt_guess)) / 2)
    }
    return (sqrt_guess)
}

#You can compare execution time with something like this...

benchmark("See the change in time from 1e+55..." = {check3x1 <- new_my_sqr(1e+55)},
          "...to 1e+56" = {check3x2 <- new_my_sqr(1e+56)},
          replications = 2,
          columns = c("test", "replications", "elapsed")
)
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it works. Using a while loop does not fill the callback stack as a recursive function would. Weird that it asks for a recursive function to be implemented - I thought it might be possible. Either way, I appreciate the insight!

Answer (score 1):

Following up on @CésarArquero's answer, which is good as far as the "avoiding recursion" part goes, but which doesn't actually address the root of your problem - which is floating point imprecision. These problems could affect both recursive and non-recursive implementations: you either need to (1) reformulate the problem to avoid the imprecision; (2) set a maximum number of iterations to avoid infinite-loop outcomes; or (3) use higher-precision arithmetic (e.g. `library("Rmpfr")` - although this is generally a last resort).

As shown below, for large values where the algorithm *doesn't* get into an infinite loop, it takes <500 iterations, so the crash at 1447 iterations (mentioned in comments by @RuiBarradas above) is probably coming from an infinite loop.

Here's an augmented version of @CésarArquero's function, which sets a max number of iterations and prints out information on progress:

```
new_my_sqr <- function(number, sqrt_guess = 1, maxit = 10000, tol = 0.001) {
    it <- 0
    dval <- abs((number/sqrt_guess) - sqrt_guess)
    while (it < maxit &&  dval > tol ) {
        sqrt_guess <- (sqrt_guess + number/sqrt_guess) / 2
        dval <- abs((number/sqrt_guess) - sqrt_guess)
        it <- it + 1
        cat(it, sqrt_guess, dval, "\n")
    }
    return (sqrt_guess)
 }
```

For 100, everything looks sensible - the distance of the guess from the answer converges smoothly to the tolerance.

```
new_my_sqr(100)
## 1 50.5 48.5198 
## 2 26.2401 22.42914 
## 3 15.02553 8.370191 
## 4 10.84043 1.615712 
## 5 10.03258 0.06505123 
## 6 10.00005 0.000105791
```

Things look more problematic if we use a much larger argument (although we still get the right answer):

```
new_my_sqr(1e30)
## ...
## 51 1.022386e+15 4.428175e+13 
## 52 1.000245e+15 490098151072 
## 53 1e+15 60049048 
## 54 1e+15 1 
## 55 1e+15 0
```

And similarly ...

```
new_my_sqr(1e54)
## 90 1.183618e+27 3.387511e+26 
## 91 1.014243e+27 2.828522e+25 
## 92 1.0001e+27 1.999934e+23 
## 93 1e+27 9.999345e+18 
## 94 1e+27 0
```

Somewhere between 1e54 and 1e56, we switch to an infinite loop (or one that would be infinite if I hadn't imposed a maximum number of iterations).

```
new_my_sqr(1e56)
## 9997 1e+28 2.199023e+12 
## 9998 1e+28 2.199023e+12 
## 9999 1e+28 2.199023e+12 
## 10000 1e+28 2.199023e+12
```

I haven't spent the time to figure out exactly how the numerical underflow problems work: the general idea is that if we try to add/subtract terms of very different magnitude, we'll get underflow.  In particular, `sqrt_guess + number/sqrt_guess` is proportional to `1 + number/(sqrt_guess^2)`, so if we ever end up at a point where `number/(sqrt_guess^2)` is very small, we're going to have catastrophic losses of precision.

I did a little bit of numerical experimentation; we don't *always* get stuck in a cycle.

[image]